# How do I correctly check for castling in chess AI?

Tags: c, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, chess

I have a chess AI that doesn't always know if it can castle or not. The rooks and kings have move counters that only allow them to participate in a castle when the value of the move counter equals zero. A problem occurs when the move counters are zero and there are no pieces blocking the castle, but an enemy piece has the ability to block the castle from afar.

For example, imagine that you are white and you want to make a queen side castle. The move counters are zero, so your pieces have made zero moves, and your white knight, bishop, and queen are gone. The you thinks that you can castle. But you actually cannot castle because there is an enemy rook with a clear line of attack that extends all the way down to the first row where you have your white rook and white king. If you castled, the king would have to cross the black rook's line of attack. You are the AI and this situation messed you up.

Now you [the human] might know a way to make you [the AI] smarter when it comes to castling. How would you, as a programmer, fix this problem such that the AI doesn't make this mistake anymore?

Here's some more information...
My board representation is int board[8][8]. I have an array that holds all possible white pieces [max 2 queens, 17 pieces total], int whitePieces[17], and array that holds all possible black pieces, int blackPieces[17]. Also, to keep track of movement, there is a moveTo[] array and a moveFrom[] array that contains, for each ply, a copy of the moving piece after it moved and before it moved. The rightmost bit of the piece integer is the y value and the 4 bit hexadecimal value one over from that is the x value. The integer piece also contains byte data representing the piece type, the piece color, the pieces location in the whitePieces array or the blackPieces array, and a movement counter that keeps track of the number of moves and is used to determine if a king or rook has moved and thus cannot castle.

Comment: Without knowing anything about how you've implemented the game, there's not much else to say than "have the AI check that none of the squares are threatened by the opponent pieces".

Comment: The AI should already know it is not allowed to move the King onto a square that is currently threatened by the opponent. Treat the castling move as moving the king to each of the squares until it reaches the castling position. If each is safe, the castle is safe.

Comment: ^ That idea with checking each space sounds like a good one. for each space between the king and the rook, I can look out diagonally for any queens or bishops and vertically for any rooks that could impede upon castling. ^

Comment: @Juhana - my board representation is int board[8][8]. I have an array that holds all possible white pieces [max 2 queens, 17 pieces total], int whitePieces[17], and array that holds all possible black pieces, int blackPieces[17]. Also, to keep track of movement, there is a moveTo[] array and a moveFrom[] array that contains, for each ply, a copy of the moving piece after it moved and before it moved. The rightmost bit of the piece integer is the y value and the 4 bit hexadecimal value one over from that is the x value. See the modified question up top.

Comment: There's a large amount of literature about writing chess programs, much of it available online. See, e.g., http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Attack+and+Defend+Maps

Comment: "max 2 queens" -- there can be up to 9 queens of the same color.

Comment: " for each space between the king and the rook" -- **no**. It should be the square the K is on, the square it passes over, and the square it lands on ... attacks on the squares between the landing square and the R do not prevent castling.

Comment: "a movement counter that keeps track of the number of moves and is used to determine if a king or rook has moved" -- all you need is one bit for each K and R.

Comment: at first I thought that by "AI" you meant the computer had to actually "learn" the rule somehow through playing, and you were wondering how to program the AI to learn such a rule

Comment: @jim-balter "all you need is one bit for each K and R". Actually all you need is one bit for each rook. If the king moves, just invalidate both rook bits.

Comment: Link posted by @JimBalter changed to https://www.chessprogramming.org/Attack_and_Defend_Maps

Comment: @Gurgeh So actually it's a kingside castling bit and a queenside castling bit. And as chux mentions in his answer, castling is prevented if the rook is taken, as well as moved.

Answer (score 4):

Your AI should have some sort of 0-ply "threat grid" that shows where every enemy piece can move next turn.  Use this info to see if the squares between the king and <strike>rook(s)</strike>the final castling location(s) are either occupied or under threat.

Comment: My board, an 8 by 8 array, is just a board with no "threat grid". That sounds like a great idea, though. Creating a threat grid after a simulated move could also determine if there would be check or if a move simulation multiply ply in would prevent castling or put the king in check. Please tell me more about this 8 by 8 threat grid array. Would you create a new threat grid for every simulated move and use it when evaluating the board?

Comment: I wouldn't say "should have". Generating attacks maps is very expensive and a lot of engines don't do it.

Comment: I knew very little of actual chess engine mechanics when I made the suggestion.  It was just how I would have done it without all the great links everyone else provided :)

Comment: Your program doesn't move the king into check.  It's simple to determine whether the king is in check (with null-move search).  The tricky part is identifying whether the square(s) next to the king are attacked.

Comment: @Daniel There's nothing tricky about it ... you just need to detect whether any given square is attacked, and then apply that to the king's square, the square next to the king, and the square 2 away from the king.

Answer (score 3):

Had same problem long time ago (1978 - in fortran).

Aside from the tests you all ready mentioned (had select rook moved, had king move, is row between them empty) you need to insure:

> [The king is not currently in check.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castling#Requirements)

With the code that determines if the King is in check, that same code can be use to see if a king would be in check in the 2 squares of interest.  So "pretend" to move the king, 1 space at a time 2 spaces left (or right) and run the test.

2 other pedantic thoughts:
The flag that sets when a rook is "moved" also needs to be set is the rook is taken.  Testing to see if a rook is in the corner is not enough as it could be another rook.

A pawn promoted to a rook and then not moved cannot be used for castling.  [castling on a file](http://www.chess.com/forum/view/general/castling-on-a-file)

---

Notes:
Rather than 17 pieces, consider staying at 16.  (You can have 0-9 queens, 0-10 rooks,  0-10 bishops, 0-8 pawns, 1 kg, etc.)

The space the rook is on or passes through may be threatened from the other side. (other color)

Comment: "The space the rook is on or passes through may be threatened from the other side." -- eh? There is no "other side" of the rook, and if the square passed through by the king is x-rayed through the king then the king is already in check. And the square the rook passes through on the queenside isn't relevant.

Comment: @JimBalter "may be threatened from the other side." --> The "other side" is the opposite color, not the king/queen side.

Comment: Ah, well, you worded that very poorly. What you meant to say is that castling is allowed regardless of whether the squares the rook is on or passes through (i.e., the queen knight's home square) are attacked (which always implies "by [not from] the other side". But it's easier to just say that the king's starting and ending square and the square in between must not be attacked, and the other squares don't matter.